# Is it considered good design to compare objects of different types?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Would you consider this evidence of bad design?

```
//FooType and BarType not in the same hierarchy
bool operator==(const FooType &, const BarType &);
bool operator<(const FooType &, const BarType &);
```

For example, if `FooType` is `double` measuring seconds since epoch and `BarType` is a tuple of three integers (year, month, and day) providing date in UTC, comparisons like above "make sense".

Have you seen such inter-type comparisons? Are they frowned upon in the C++ community?

Comment: Depends who will be maintaining the code :) I'd lean towards implementing it as a class method, i.e. BarType::CompareToEpoch. Btw, long int would be better than double for measuring seconds since epoch...

Comment: I think the reason this was put on hold is going to be your answer.

Comment: I would say yes, since `operator==(const FooType &)` should probably be a method of the `BarType` class, not a function.

Comment: Consider making a conversion constructor for the other type instead. Even with something like a constructor taking a day, month, and year type, you could still do `if (time == {Day(13), Month(5), Year(1996)})`

Comment: @Alex1985, a double can hold integers up to 2**53 without rounding, giving you 284836042 years of seconds. Isn't that enough?

Comment: @chepner: Nah, symmetric binary operators should be free functions, not members.  If you just want to see the declaration as part of the class definition, use `friend`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Personal vision and experience**

I personally do not frown upon the comparison between different types. I even encourage it, as it may improve code readability; making what you are doing seem more logical. Outside of the basic number types, and maybe a string and a character, I find it hard to give you a logical intra-type comparison, and I don't remember having met many. I have met alot of arithmetic operators used like this though.

**How to use them**

You should be careful with what you are doing, they are used scarcely for a reason. If you offer a function for the comparison of two different types, the outcome should be logical and what the user intuitively expected. It is also desirelable to write good documentation for it. Mark Ransom already said it, but it is good if users can compare in both directions. If you think your comparison is not sufficiently clear enough with an operator, you should think about using a named function. This is also a very good solution if your operator can have multiple meanings.

**What can go wrong**

You do not have full control over what the user will do with what you have written. tletnes gave a good example of this, where two integers are compared, but the outcome has no meaning. In contradiction to this, the comparison of two different types can be very right. A float and an integer both representing seconds, can be well compared.

**Arithmetic operators**

Next to logical, I would like to show an intra-type example with arithmetic operators. Arithmetic operators are much like logical operators when talking about intra-type usage.

Say you have an operator + for a two dimentional vector and a square. What does this do? The user might think it scales the square, but another user is sure it translates! These kinds of issues can be very frustrating to your users. You can solve this by providing good documentation, but what I personally prefer, is specifically named functions, like Translate.

**Conclusion**

Intra-type logical operators can be useful and make clean code, but bad usage makes everything just more complicated.

Comment: One thing to note in the "What can go wrong" section is that the number of supported comparisons for different types can cause the number of required functions to support these operations to blow up quickly.  2 types, 4 functions (a==a, a==b, b==a, b==b).  3 types, 9 functions.  It's N^2 complexity (assuming reflexive & symmetric properties).

Answer (score 4):

To start with, there's nothing wrong with using free functions instead of member functions, in fact it's recommended practice. See Scott Meyer's [How Non-Member Functions Improve Encapsulation](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197). You'll want to provide the comparisons in both directions though:

```
bool operator==(const FooType &, const BarType &);
bool operator==(const BarType &, const FooType &);
```

Second, it's perfectly acceptable to provide these comparisons *if the comparisons make sense*. The standard library for example allows you to compare `std::complex` values for equality with floating point, but not less-than.

The one thing you want to avoid is comparisons that don't make sense. In your example one of the time values is a double, which means the comparison would occur for any floating point or integer value once you take standard promotions into account. This is probably more than you intended since there's no way to determine if any particular value represents a time. The loss of type checking means that there's a potential for unintended bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Good design would dicatate that you should only compare values of compatible meaning. Generally type is a good clue to meaning, but is not the last word, in fact in many cases two values of the same type may have incompatible meaning, such as the followng two integers:

```
int seconds = 3 //seconds
int length = 2; //square inches
if(seconds >= length){
    //what does this mean?
}
```

In this example we compare length to seconds, however there is not a meningful relationship between the two.

```
int test_duration = 3 //minutes
float elapsed_time = 2.5; //seconds
if((test_duration * 60) >= elapsed_time ){
    //tes is done
}
```

In this examaple we compare two values of differing types (and units) however their meanings are still compatible (they both represent time) so (assuming there is a good reason why the two were stored that way (e.g. ease of using an API etc.)  this is a good design.

Answer (score 0):

According to Stepanov's rules (see Elements of Programming), equality is tightly connected with copying (construction and assignment) (and also inequality).

So, if the objects represent equal values then go ahead, make them equality comparable but think of these four operations at the same time (equality, [copy]construction, assignment and inequality). 
By extension, also conversion (cast operation or construction on the other side) back and forth from the different types.

It is also implicitly connected to any "regular" function you can apply to these values. 
Stepanov defines two values to be equal if any (regular) function applied to them gives equal results.

I would say also that, even if you can compare two objects equal and construct one from each other, if the set of common functions (generic or not) you can apply to both is not a relevant set or their results typical yield unequal values then there is little value in comparing the different types of objects.
Worst of all, what if one of the types has fundamentally more functions than the other? Can one maintain reflexivity?

Finally there is the consideration of algorithmic complexity, if comparing the two objects is *O(N^2)* or higher (where *N* is the "size" of the objects in some measure), then it is understood that there is little value in comparing objects at all. (See John Lakos' talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3xI1HJUy7Q)

So, as you see there is more to it than just coming up with a comparison criterion to fill in the body of `operator==`, or whether it is a good practice, that is just the start. 
Equality is so fundamental that percolates into the meaning of all your program.